# Attempting to implement redirection. Having trouble understanding file descriptors and dup2

Tags: c

I am supposed to be implementing a shell with redirection capabilities, but I am having trouble making heads or tails as to how to work with file descriptors.
Here in my test.c file, I am experimenting, trying to pipe test from 'python --version' into a file called 'out'.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[], char *const envp[])
{
/***/TOKENIZER *tester;
    int pid = 0;
    int pipefd[2];
    char buffer = 0;

    pipe(pipefd); 
    pid = fork();
    pipefd[1] = open("out", O_WRONLY | O_TRUNC | O_CREAT, S_IRUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IWGRP | S_IWUSR);

    if(pid == 0){
        close(pipefd[1]);
        dup2(pipefd[0], STDIN_FILENO); 
        close(pipefd[0]);
        while(read(STDIN_FILENO, &buffer, 1) > 0){
            write(STDOUT_FILENO, &buffer, 1);
        }

        close(pipefd[0]);
        _exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }else{
        close(pipefd[0]);
        dup2(pipefd[1], STDOUT_FILENO); 
        close(pipefd[1]);

        write(STDOUT_FILENO, "asdsd\n", 6);

        char* ver[2];
        ver[1] = "--version";
        execvp("python", ver);
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }
    free(tester);


    return 0;
```

EDIT: Realized I was mixing parts of redirection and piping up. Here is some redirection code which I am attempting to run.

```
int out = open("output.txt", O_WRONLY | O_TRUNC | O_CREAT, S_IRUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IWGRP | S_IWUSR);

dup2(out, 1);
close(out);

char* ver[2];
ver[1] = "--version";
execvp("python", ver);
exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);

return 0;
```

I am attempting to get the Python versioning into output.txt, but I seem to be missing something since it's not working.

EDIT 2: Looks like it's executing, but it's outputting to standard out instead of output.txt.

```
int out = open("output.txt", O_WRONLY | O_TRUNC | O_CREAT, S_IRUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IWGRP | S_IWUSR);
dup2(out, STDOUT_FILENO);

char* ver[3];
ver[0] = "python";
ver[1] = "--version";
ver[2] = NULL;
execvp("python", ver);
perror("exec");

return 0;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    int pid = 0;
    int pipefd[2];
    char buffer = 0;

    pipe(pipefd); 
    pid = fork();
```

So far, so good. You've created a pipe, with its two file descriptors stored in `pipefd[0]` and `pipefd[1]`, and created a child process.

```
    pipefd[1] = open("out", O_WRONLY | O_TRUNC | O_CREAT, S_IRUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IWGRP | S_IWUSR);
```

Oh no! You just overwrote a perfectly good file descriptor (the write end of the pipe) with a different one, pointing to the regular file named "out".

Are you trying to do regular file redirection, or a pipe? Before you try to implement a shell, you should a least know that these are two different things. If you're trying to mimic `python --version > out` then you should notice that there's no pipe character in that command line, so why would you imagine that a pipe is involved in the implementation?

Also, since you did this after the fork, both processes are running now, and both of them are going to do the open, including the creating and truncating side effects. That can't be what you wanted.

I'll stop there, since the rest of the program won't make sense until you fix this part.

But a few random notes:

- 3-arg `main` has been obsolete for quite some time. Use `getenv()` or `environ` to look up environment variables.
- A single-byte buffer is not efficient, and it wouldn't be much harder to use a bigger one.
- It's weird - not necessarily a fatal problem but definitely unusual - to do the exec in the parent and not in the child.

Comment: Ahh, you're right. Looks like I got confused and mixed up elements from both < and |. That's what I get for researching them concurrently, haha. And yeah, the envp was a holdover from last month when I had to use execve and not execvp. I could probably drop that. Thanks! I'll look into your answer!

Comment: Anyways, I just added some simple redirection code which hasn't been working, so I have a feeling that I'm not comprehending dup2() correctly.

Comment: You need to put something in `ver[0]` before you try to exec. Even if python doesn't care about its `argv[0]`, the kernel requires a pointer to a legitimate string. or the exec will fail. After the exec, instead of `EXIT_SUCCESS` you should print an error message (i.e. `perror("exec");`) because exec never returns unless there was an error. Your other syscalls could use some error checking too...

Comment: And of vourse you need to have a `NULL` at the end of `ver`, so make it 3 elements long and set `ver[2]=NULL`

Comment: Ahh, okay. Looks like that started execution up again. It looks like it's still going to standard out, though. (Code posted above)

Comment: Congratulations. You've successfully imitated `python --version > output.txt`. Try it from your shell prompt. Python sends the version number to `stderr`!